# Looking for a quote on dynamic system identification

Tags: control, control-theory

Does anyone know of a quote by an eminent control theorist or controls engineer or book author who I could reference who said something along the lines of the following:

> The process of control system design begins with understanding the dynamic behaviour of the system that is to be optimized.

I'm sure someone did I just don't know who!

Comment: I wonder who didn't say that.

Comment: Maybe if I ask a different way: Does anyone know of a methodology or step-wise approach for control system design that would show system identification as an early step in the process?

Comment: Won’t that be chapter 1, page 1 of any decent text book on the topic...

Comment: "... understanding the dynamic behavior ...": Many classic systems already have a minimal model (eg DC motor). In the first chapters the components are considered to be known. A proper understanding for system identification usually requires a discipline entirely dedicated to this.

Comment: Maybe if someone just can give me a well-known practical text-book I could reference.  There are quite a lot (I'm not a control engineer).

Comment: I found one in a Dutch course text: "For the success of a control system design the depth of understanding of the dynamical properties of the system and the signals often is more important than the a priori qualifications of the particular design method." (p1 from: http://wwwhome.math.utwente.nl/~meinsmag/dmcs/dmcs0708.pdf)

Comment: I am not a control system engineer. But I think that in the real world it is often the case that the engineers don't have deep knowledge of how the system responds and no analytical model, and they just use a PID to control it until it works well enough.

Comment: True.  I should have specified that my application is multi-input multi-output (MIMO) and non-linear so a model-based approach is going to be important.  Hence the search for a good quote about the importance of understanding the actual system dynamics...

Comment: I don't see how you need or want to provide that quote. It's sort of like saying, "The process of designing an electronic circuit begins with understanding the electrical behavior of the components selected." And your comment about about what engineers often do (grab a PID and twiddle the knobs until it works adequately) simply shows that, with experience, it is not often necessary to perform a formal analysis of a system in order to control it. An analogy would be with a desired amplifier performance: just grab an op amp with adequate bandwidth and set the gain of the feedback network.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast For the most common, mundane, and numerous applications anyways...I don't see twiddling knobs working so well for aircraft or space craft ;)

Answer (score 1):

I will post quotes here as I come across them:

**1.**

> The most important task confronting the control system analyst is developing a mathematical model of the process of interest. In many situations the essence of the analytical design problem is in the modeling: once that is done the rest of the analysis falls quickly into place.

*Control System Design: An Introduction to State-Space Methods, by Bernard Friedland*

**2.**

This [3 minute YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noOJF6Qa7a8) proposes a nice, simple five-step process:

> STUDY -> MODEL -> ANALYZE -> DESIGN -> VERIFY

[image: Control System Design Process Diagram]

Credit: Jonathan Sprinkle, Aug 30, 2013

**3.**

> The process of designing a control system usually makes many demands of the
>   engineer or engineering team. These demands often emerge in a step by step design
>   procedure as follows:
>   1. Study the system (plant) to be controlled and obtain initial information about the control objectives.
>   2. Model the system and simplify the model, if necessary.
>   ...

*Multivariable Feedback Control Analysis and design by S. Skogestad and I. Postlethwaite, 2001*

**4.**

> The construction of knowledge-driven models starts by analyzing the dominant phenomena at play, making simplifying assumptions and writing material, momentum, and/or energy balances around each part of the system under investigation.

*Bonvin et al. Linking Models and Experiments, Ind. Eng. Chem. Res. 2016, 55, 6891−6903*

**5.**

> An essential feature of control and optimisation strategies is the availability of mathematical models that accurately describe the steady-state and dynamic characteristics of the process in the whole operating range, including its non-linear behaviour.

*Hodouin et al. State of the art and challenges in mineral processing control, Control Engineering Practice 9 (2001) 995–1005*

**6.**

From course notes for [GEL-2005 Linear Systems and Control Course](https://www.ulaval.ca/les-etudes/cours/repertoire/detailsCours/gel-2005-systemes-et-commande-lineaires.html), U Laval, André Desbiens, 2019:

> Il faut en effet bien connaître comment se comporte le procédé si on désire bien le contrôler.

Which roughly translates as:

> You really need to know how the process behaves if you want to control it.

Comment: You should be careful, this is not entirely true, or at least not thorough. There's a whole segment of data-driven control design which does not require a process model. Even the Ziegler-Nichols PID tables do not strictly require a model for a system, only experimental data. One could argue that any particular design method should be best suited for a specific 'class' of systems, albeit its model unknown.

Comment: Yes good point.  This quote emphasizes model-building.  Whereas I was actually interested in a quote that emphasizes "understanding the dynamic behaviour of the system" as the first step regardless of the eventual control system design (at least for MIMO systems).  Still haven't found a good one...